How can I anchor a slightly oversized home to new concrete foundation?
We are moving a house measuring just over 24 ft by 40 ft to a new concrete basement foundation. It appears that the foundation will be a couple inches smaller than the house. What is the method of attachment if the rim joist and sill plate don’t match up?

Rim joists are a little more than a cover(some structural), so you just need a second piece(like a L) to go from the rim joist to the sill plate, to finish the cover on the bottom.  With 2 inch actual measurement, A 2x4 will be almost the right size.  2 inch space plus 1.5 inch wide(short side) rim equals 3.5 inches which is the actual measurement  of a 2x4.

"I think" and  "it appears"  are scarey words when dealing with setting a house on a foundation.  Not really sure if this is a DIY but get some accurate measurements.

Define "new concrete foundation."  Slab?  Walls?

Dimensionally it sounds like what you are moving is a manufactured home.  Depending on the year built it may not have things like rim joists .  You will need to be more specific about what you house is built like.  Also the dimensions need to be stated clearly.  In many instances having the home an inch over the foundation is better for the structure and prevents wicking of rain water.  However as other have said there isn't much information here.

@Huesmann, I revised "basement" to "foundation". I realize now that this left some ambiguity. Corrected.

The usual solution is to make the foundation contractor (re)build the new foundation the correct size. Depend's who's at fault for it being the wrong size as to who gets to pay for that, though.

Ok, thank you for your response. Sorry asking correct questions I believe it is approx. a 24’ x 40’ modular single level  to a 24’ x 40’ superior wall concrete basement. When I say approx all I can get from people are that the level being moved is 3-4 inches larger on the 40’ side. So wondering how to attach to the already placed sill plate on top of the superior wall basement if sill plate and rim joist don’t match up??

You leave a lot of detail left to the imagination here. I'll make some assumptions and suggest a few things:

While the house is lifted, fasten existing or new sill plates well to the rim joists. This may ultimately be handled by lapped wall sheathing, but it can't hurt.

Once the house is in place, drill through the sill plate and into the foundation wall for expanding anchor bolts.

If you can't do that due to clearance or whatever, set anchor bolts before positioning the house, and carefully drill the sill plate for those locations.

Otherwise, cut short segments of 3x2 steel angle and use them as brackets between the sill plate and the foundation wall, using lag screws and expanding anchors as appropriate.

You could also run straps periodically from the joists on the interior to the inner face of the foundation wall. This would serve the same function as fastening the rim.


Whatever you decide, run it by your local inspection authority for approval.
